# Typing on open start menu doesn't search the menu any longer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I updated my Windows 10 via:

`2020-01 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1909 (KB4532695)` and
`2020-01 Cumulative Update for .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8 (KB4534132)`

Before the update, when clicking on the Windows start button in the bottom left corner, I could just start typing in anything and it would search through the Program Files etc., for example: Click on the Windows logo, type in update, and it would show "Windows Update".

Now, after the update, when I click on the Windows logo and start typing, it moves over to what looks like Cortana, and no matter what I type in it doesn't seem to search, and it doesn't show anything other than the box itself.

How do I restore the original search function when clicking on the Windows logo, without having to remove the new updates?

[image]

Comment: Is it not just because the black bar up the side dissapears (and the search box is actually in the same location as before) [Like this](https://snipboard.io/Dm90IP.jpg). Oh wait - it doesn't search at all? time to rebuild indexes maybe??

Comment: I think this is a duplicate but I can't find the original at the moment. I seem to remember that it is the Bing search that is timing out. Found it!

Comment: Again, MS has released updates that break existing functionality. After trying v. 1909 and finding it also broke search in Explorer, I reverted to v. 1903.

Comment: Well i'll be darn. Adding the key "BingSearchEnabled" and leaving it at 0 worked (had to restart the explorer after)